# Accessing Arrays in Rose Compiler

Tags: c++, arrays, compiler-construction, rose-compiler-framework

I'm new to stackoverflow, and new to using the rose compiler. 
I'm trying to get the total number of arrays accessed in a function (not for every array access, but for individual arrays). 
Here's what I have so far:

```
//for each function body
SgFunctionDeclaration *func = isSgFunctionDeclaration(*p);
SgFunctionDefinition *defn = func->get_definition();
Rose_STL_Container<SgNode*> arrayAccess = NodeQuery::querySubTree(defn,V_SgArrayType);
for (Rose_STL_Container<SgNode*>::iterator iter = arrayAccess.begin(); iter!= arrayAccess.end(); iter++ ) {
//in here i check if any iterators point to the same thing, and only increment counter if they do not point to the same
```

This seems to work for some examples, but for others it doesn't detect any arrays.. 
It seems the way I'm querying for array is not correct? Does anyone know about this?

Comment: Why don't you print out the subtrees offered by iterator, to see what they look like?  I'm not a Rose expert, but it appears that querySubTree must walk the defn tree looking for matches to V_SgArrayType.  What exactly is V_SgArrayType?

Comment: Yes, that's what I did. I printed out the querySubTree but sometime's there's nothing in it, even though there are arrays being accessed in the function. V_SgArrayType means that the node is an array type. Another type would be V_SgForStatement, which means that the node is a for loop. That's my understanding so far, but I may be missing something here...